# Calculating value of definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $$ f(x) = x + \int_{0}^{1} t(x+t) f(t) dt $$

Then how to calculate $$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx $$

Comment: What hypotheses does $f$ satisfy?

Comment: Only the first equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can write
$$f(x)=x+x\int_0^1tf(t)dt+\int_0^1t^2f(t)dt=x+ax+b$$
where
$$a=\int_0^1tf(t)dt=\int_0^1t(t+at+b)dt$$
$$b=\int_0^1t^2f(t)dt=\int_0^1t^2(t+at+b)dt$$
Now solve this system.